# Integrity constraint violation: 1452 however the records exist in the 'parent tables'

Tags: php, mysql

Im battling with a php and mysql again. I keep encountering a SQL violation error:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`insights`.`proposal`, CONSTRAINT `proposal_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`course_code`) REFERENCES `course_details` (`course_code`))

however, when i serialise the information from a php form ready to use in my insert query i encounter this SQL error. I know the course_code and user_record_id are not a problem because i have manually inserted these using the PhpMyAdmin and it has added the record successfully.

The values from the form are okay too. I have used var_dump to see whats being held in the variables and it is correct.

The structure for proposal table:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `proposal`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `proposal`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `proposal` (
`proposal_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `source` enum('Student','Supervisor','Other') NOT NULL,
  `proposal_title` text NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `course_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_record_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- RELATIONS FOR TABLE `proposal`:
--   `course_code`
--       `course_details` -> `course_code`
--   `user_record_id`
--       `user` -> `user_record_id`
--

ALTER TABLE `proposal`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`proposal_id`), ADD KEY `course_code` (`course_code`,`user_record_id`), ADD KEY `user_record_id` (`user_record_id`);

ALTER TABLE `proposal`
ADD CONSTRAINT `proposal_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`course_code`) REFERENCES `course_details` (`course_code`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
ADD CONSTRAINT `proposal_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`user_record_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_record_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

my insert query:

```
$insertProp = $db_conx->prepare(" INSERT INTO `insights`.`proposal` (`source`, `proposal_title`, `description`, `date_added`, `course_code`, `user_record_id`) VALUES ('Supervisor', ':title', ':description', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ':course', ':user_record_id')");

        $insertProp->bindParam(':user_record_id', $user_record_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertProp->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertProp->bindParam(':description', $description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertProp->bindParam(':course', $course, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertProp->execute();
```

Anyone know why its having an issue and a possible workaround please?

Thanks